# libvlc_media_player_get_time returning zero

Tags: c++, c, video, vlc, libvlc

hey people I was writing a simple application to run a video stream using libvlc.But it seem that libvlc_media_player_get_time() function is not working properly.It is returning zero every time it is being called no matter how much video has been played.So can you please find out the possible remedies for it.
Also is there any signal handler or function in libvlc which can raise an event when we reach the end of stream so that I can pause for a moment till more data get stacked up?
All the replies in this regard will be appreciated.
With Regards,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with different types of video? (i.e. different codecs). Posting some code would also help

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I see the same behavior with VLC 1.1.12. This depends on the type of media being played. I have a .ts file that always returns 0, but YouTube videos show the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

if you're streaming incoming data it might always return 0